# what is the Regular Expression of this sample (LINE QUEUE BRANCH)

Tags: regex

please help me figure out how to get the REGEX of this:

```
(LINE<space>QUEUE<space>BRANCH)
```

I'm try to do this,

```
^LINE+[0-9]+(MKT|TGT)$
```

Queue number should be dynamic from 1-1000

Thanks in advance anyone!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expression.

```
^LINE *([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000) *(MKT|TGT)$
```

- This will allow `0` or more spaces between each part.
- `[1-9][0-9]{0,2}` matches any number between `1`–`999` or match `1000`

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dQ8dR7/1)

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you,

```
  ^LINE ([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000) (MKT|TGT)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/30)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex would be,

```
^LINE \b(?:1000|[1-9](?:[0-9]?[0-9])?)\b (?:MKT|TGT)$
```

The number ranges from 1 to 1000 would be present at the middle of the line.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/28)